# fonts folder can't be found in iReport on MacOS

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport version 3.7.4 for my development on MacOS. One of the templates is utilizing custom font, I have installed it. And now when I try to switch to Preview following exception is being thrown:

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/iReport.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/ireport/fonts (No such file or directory)

I was able to navigate to that folder in my Finder, it exists. I have no idea why iReport complains about this path.

Please advise. THX.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on Linux) I had an image url parameter and had to explicitly set the attribute **isForPropmting** to false like this:

```
<parameter name="LOGO_URL" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```